# NET Core App Memory keeps growing even if properly Disposed/Unreferenced

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpwebrequest

I have a C# .NET core tool that scrapes HTML, 10K-250K+ entries. It's stable and all memory is properly handled and disposed `(WebRequests, Responses, Streams)`, nothing is stored in memory as output data is written directly to files but the memory usage keeps growing... and growing... and growing. All that's in memory is `byte[]` and then `string` versions of the actively processed pages which are under 500 at a time. Then the work ends and everything related to its activity is disposed, all units of works lose all references, the memory does not decrease. It stays in 3-5GB of RAM used.

Finally, all activity ends, I exit the function where the work is done, I put it in a wait state via `Console.ReadKey()` but the memory does not get freed even after 15mins of no activity in the tool. Now... if I write a GC.Collect at the end, memory instantly drops to 30MB from 3-5GB. Huh... That's the expected behavior given the code, actual memory usage should not exceed 250MB RAM.

If I wrote this same thing in C++, I would not exceed 250MB of RAM no matter what at any time as C++ *tends* to free the memory I'm freeing in code. It's nice that way.

**The question is**: *Why is this obscene memory use not cleared even after minutes of idle in the tool but if I force a Collect it instantly drops to where it should be? And why does memory usage keep going up if I know all objects are disposed and lose all references after handled.*

Comment: Just because it is Disposed/unreferenced doesn't mean that the GC will clean it up it just means that it *can clean it up* when the time arises. There has to be memory pressure. If there isn't any, then there really isn't a good reason to run the GC because it takes a lot of time/processor to do a full GC.

Comment: are you sure all of them are disposed? are you using any COM object??

Comment: Can you try with another Wait mechanism? A `WaitHandle.WaitOne(new Timespan(0,15,0));` or so. or make it spin a bit.

Comment: @Steve. There is no COM and no leaks. Once I force a Collect it goes down to almost nothing. I also tracked `Finalizers()` in objects to make sure it all works properly.

Comment: @RonBeyer The term `memory pressure` does not sound that great when you see an app idle and all internal data disposed/unreferenced hangs around with 4GBs of RAM. It's not normal.

Comment: @CodeAngry force GC CAN clean up some COM leaks. Your scenario where mem goes down dramatically does indeed sound like COM leak.

Comment: @Steve I only use WebRequest/WebResponses. Nothing else outside of MemoryStream, Encoding for decoding charsets and StringReader parsing for going over HTML. All in `using` blocks.

Comment: Just to clarify, `Dispose()` has nothing to do with the GC; the GC will collect, or not collect objects, regardless of whether they are disposed. Also, as I just tested for another question, MemoryStream does not 'forget' its internal buffer when disposed.